# Why say "〜、皆には出来る。" instead of " 〜、皆は出来る。" in this context?

Tags: particle-に, particle-は

The sentence in a translation:

> 将来を見据えながら点と点を結ぶということなど、皆**には**できません。
>   While looking at the future, one cannot see how to connect the dots.

My assumption is that the following is the "base" sentence. Then, to add meaning, a `に` is placed before the `は`. Maybe it adds emphasis (or something)?

> 将来を見据えながら点と点を結ぶということなど、皆**は**できません。

I don't think I've ever seen a `は` and then have a `に` placed behind it to add meaning.

*However*, if the "base" sentence should be thought of as:

> 将来を見据えながら点と点を結ぶということなど、皆**に**できません。

Then I am ok with regard to particles. Placing a `は` after a `に` seems pretty common.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24955/5010 The "base" should be 皆にできません. One can say "君にできる?", "彼に分かる?" etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The に form is the "base" sentence here, and the は is added for emphasis.

One key to understanding how できる happens grammatically is that できる is often describing **the thing that can be done**, instead of the people or things doing the thing.  Sometimes a closer gloss is *doable* rather than *can* -- English *can* describes the people or things doing the thing, while *doable* describes the thing that can be done.

In your sample sentence, the topic is こと, and all the stuff to the left of こと tells us what kind of こと it is.  The できません applies to this こと -- this こと is *not doable* -- and the 皆**に** here tells us who or what this こと is *not doable **by***.

#### Addendum

The grammar for できる is at least partially attributable to the historical development of the term.  [See this other post for details.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/etymology-of-%E5%87%BA%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B-dekiru/18068#18068)

Comment: Are there any other verbs that act like this?

Comment: Several; but, they only seem odd because the standard English translations are adapted to use natural English words. For example, 私には日本語が分かる is naturally translated as "I understand Japanese", but literally it's more like "Japanese is clear/understandable to me".

Comment: Thank you for the write-up. So is this "に" compulsive or optional? Both "私はできる" and "私にはできる" seem quite common, but in op's example the  "に" seems compulsive. I'm really confused about when it can be omitted.

Answer (score 9):

### Reason for using「は」

The「は」provides contrast. It provides an unspoken (in English) and ***contrasting parenthetical context*** as shown below.

> 日本語の読み書きは**皆には**できません。

- Not *everyone* can read and write Japanese  (**but** *some* people can)
- Not *just anyone* can read and write Japanese  (**but** *many* people can)
- Not *all of (you)* can read and write Japanese  (**but** *some* of you can)
- Not *all of (them)* can read and write Japanese  (**but** *some* of them can)

### Reason for using「に」

The reason for this is that できる is describing the "possession" or "existence" of a capability to do something.

> 日本語の読み書きは**皆に**できません。

So just as you would say,

「野菜は**冷蔵庫にある**よ」or「コーヒーは**キッチンにはない**よ」

to describe the **existence** of *things* at a *location*,
you also use the same construction to talk about the **existence** of *ability* in a *person*.

「**あなたには**できる」 or 「**わたしには**できない」

Taking a cue from Eiríkr Útlendi's answer, you could think of the **に** here as marking an ability possessed ***by*** a person.