# How to denote the object and the subject of potential form verbs clearly?

Tags: grammar, potential-form

The source in where I studied told me that you mark the object of potential form with が particle instead of を particle because potential form is just a state, no actual action is taken. It specifically told me that を can be used but が is better. I know how to make sentences where I'm the subject. 山が登れない : I can't climb the mountain. 彼が言っていることが聞こえない : I can't hear what he is saying. But what if I want to say "He can't eat apples" or "Alice can't go to school" or even "Bob can't kill Tanaka". With が、を、は I could be mistaken in saying "Tanaka can't kill Bob" instead of "Bob can't kill Tanaka". Can が also denote the subject or only the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particle you are looking for is に.

- [Use of に in 「私には本物の若殿様がわかります」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24955/5010)
- [Why say "〜、皆には出来る。" instead of " 〜、皆は出来る。" in this context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36481/5010)

> He can't eat apples.
>   ≒ 彼はりんごを食べられない。
>   ≒ 彼にりんごは食べられない。
>
> Bob can't kill Tanaka.
>   ≒ ボブは田中を殺せない。
>   ≒ ボブに田中は殺せない。
>
> He can't climb this mountain.
>   ≒ 彼はこの山を登れない。
>   ≒ 彼にこの山は登れない。
>
> the reason why he can't climb this mountain
>   ≒ 彼がこの山を登れない理由
>   ≒ 彼にこの山が登れない理由
>
> He can't hear what I am saying.
>   ≒ 彼に私が言っていることは聞こえない。
>   ≒ 彼に私の言っていることは聞こえない。 ([ga-no conversion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010))
>
> Alice can't go to school.
>   アリスは学校に行けない。
>   (You cannot say アリスに学校に行けない. Probably because there is already に?)

(Different words are topicalized using は, but I don't know which is "better"...)

*EDIT: changed the fifth example above for consistency.*